# iOS-Chart: Select the data point programmatically but get the highLight is NAN

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I'd like to select the last data point programmatically and draw gradient background, but I got the highLight is NAN so I can't get the coordinate to draw the gradient.I used :

```
chartView.highlightValue(Highlight(x: lastEntry.x, y: lastEntry.y, dataSetIndex: 0), callDelegate: true)
```

to select the last entry, and draw the gradient in the delegate function:

`func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight)`

but the highlight is NAN and then crash
I also tried using "valueToPixelMatrix" way to get the coordinate, but the results are different from the highlight.xPx and highlight.yPx,
i would like to ask how can i get the correct coordinate of data point on Chart View. Thank you.

Comment: How you are getting lastEntry to highlight ?

Comment: chartView.highlightValue(Highlight(x: lastEntry.x, y: lastEntry.y, dataSetIndex: 0), callDelegate: true)

Comment: no not this one I am asking how you are getting LastEntry ?

Comment: I have an array to draw the data point, and I get the LastEntry from the last element in arrray, this data point did selected but I can’t get the correct coordinate of this data point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think like you use wrong way for customization of highlighting.  You don't need to use this delegate function for drawing.

You need to create your own renderer class and override `drawHighlighted(context: CGContext, indices: [Highlight])` method. In this place you will get access to correct coordinates. 
Keep in your mind, that you need instantiate from properly parent class in depend of type of your chart view. (E.g. `CandleStickChartRenderer`, `BarChartRenderer`, `LineChartRenderer`, etc.)

Don't forget set instance of your custom renderer class to renderer property of your chart view.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    guard let chartDataSet = data.set else {return} // get dataSet used by chart
    guard let chartView = chartView as? LineChartView else {return}
    let transform = chartView.getTransformer(forAxis: chartDataSet.axisDependency)
    let pt = transform.pixelForValues(x: highlight.x, y: highlight.y)
    
    if highlightMark == nil {
        setHighlightMark() // create a custom view
        self.addSubview(highlightMark!)
    }
    let convertPt = self.convert(pt, from: chartView)
    highlightMark?.center = CGPoint(x: convertPt.x, y: convertPt.y)
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate of function?